# Remove row below conditionally in dataframe and add values together in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with 3 columns: Name, Country, and Sales.

I'd like to sum the Sales column by Names that are both identical *and* occur consecutively. Then I'd like to remove all rows but the first occurrence of a series, replacing the value of Sales with the series sum.

For example:

```
Name,Country,Sales
A,V,100
A,W,100
B,X,100
B,Y,100
A,Z,100
```

Would be reduced to:

```
Name,Country,Sales
A,V,200
B,X,200
A,Z,100
```

Anyone got any idea how to do this?

Comment: How are you deciding which Country value to keep? Are you wanting to keep the earliest occurring value, or would you only really need the Name and Sales values?

Comment: Yeah just the earliest name, but only if they appear in a row. I.e.  A,A,Z would remove the second A and add the two sales together. But A,Z,A would keep everything

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Series=rleid(Name)) %>%
  mutate(Sales = sum(Sales)) %>%
  filter(1:n() == 1)
```

Output:

```
   Name Country Sales Series
1     A       V   200      1
2     B       X   200      2
3     A       Z   100      3
```

Sample data:

```
require(data.table)
df <- fread("Name,Country,Sales
            A,V,100
            A,W,100
            B,X,100
            B,Y,100
            A,Z,100")
```

Comment: But then they would add ALL the names together I only want the ones when they are in a row.

Comment: @nonein - Okay, I think I understand what you're asking now. I was confused by your use of the word "row", which is in this case meaning consecutive. I've edited my answer to solve your question now, and I've edited your question to better account for this phrasing.

Comment: @nonein - Please remember to select a solution to help the community know this has been solved and to help people with the same question find their answer even faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "B"), Country = c("X", "Y", 
"Z"), Sales = c(100L, 100L, 100L)), .Names = c("Name", "Country", 
"Sales"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

`dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
ans <- df %>%
         group_by(rleid(Name)) %>%
         summarise(Name = unique(Name), Sales=sum(Sales)) %>%
         select(-1)
```

Output

```
   Name Sales
  <chr> <int>
1     A   200
2     B   100
```

Alternative example

```
newdf <- rbind(df, data.frame(Name=c("A","A","B","B"),
                              Country=c("A","B","C","D"),
                              Sales=c(100,100,100,100)))
ans <- newdf %>%
         group_by(rleid(Name)) %>%
         summarise(Name = unique(Name), Sales=sum(Sales)) %>%
         select(-1)
```

Output

```
    Name Sales
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      A   200
2      B   100
3      A   200
4      B   200
```

Comment: @nonein - I think my answer should give you the output you expect

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using `sqldf`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("Name,Country,Sales
            A,V,100
            A,W,100
            B,X,100
            B,Y,100
            A,Z,100")

df$rle = rleid(df$Name)

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select min(rowid) as row_names, 
              Name,
              Country,
              sum(Sales) as Sales
      from df group by rle", row.names = TRUE)

#   Name Country Sales
# 1    A       V   200
# 3    B       X   200
# 5    A       Z   100
```

`row.names = TRUE` searches for a column named `row_names` and treats it as row names, so `min(rowid)` will not show up as a new column if I set it `as row_names`.